# Android achartengine labels overlapping

Tags: android, achartengine

I have an issue with x axis labels overlapping. Is there any way to set the spacing between the values to prevent this?

[image]

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by setting the max x range value to be a small number e.g. 3. This forced the data points to be more spread out which in turn forced the x axis labels to be more spread out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(double spacing);
```

I think this would help.